# Can variables be decorated?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

Decorating function or method in python is wonderful.

```
@dec2
@dec1
def func(arg1, arg2, ...):
    pass
#This is equivalent to:

def func(arg1, arg2, ...):
    pass
func = dec2(dec1(func))
```

I was wondering if decorating variable in python is possible.

```
@capitalize
@strip
foo = ' foo '

print foo # 'FOO'
#This is equivalent to:
foo = foo.strip().upper()
```

I couldn't find anything on the subject via searching.

Comment: [How can I decorate an instance of a callable class?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24122444/2301450)

Comment: I can't understand the point of asking the question. Why not just **try it**?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, decorator syntax is only valid on functions and classes.

Just pass the value to the function:

```
foo = capitalize(strip(' foo '))
```

or replace the variable by the result:

```
foo = ' foo '
foo = capitalize(strip(foo))
```

Decorators exist because you can't just wrap a function or class declaration in a function call; simple variables you *can*.

Comment: I guess they wanted to keep it strictly to methods, then.