# How to apply a decorator to a MagicMock function in unittest?

Tags: python, decorator, python-unittest, magicmock

I am writing a test for a library using `unittest`. Real usage of the library would look like:

```
from mylibrary import Connection

con = Connection()

@con.notification(int)
def my_callback(value):
    print('New value:', value)

con.add_notification(my_callback)

# A remote change will now trigger the callback
```

Now I want to mock the callback in a unit test so I can verify it got called with the expected arguments:

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock

class LibraryTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    # ...

    def my_test(self):
        mock_callback = mock.MagicMock()
        self.con.add_notification(mock_callback)
        self.con.write(3.14)  # Trigger change

        mock_callback.assert_called_once()  # This succeeds
```

This verifies the callback got triggered, but the callback was not decorated (this is needed to specify the variable type). How can I decorate a mocked object?
Pseudo code to illustrate what I am looking for: (not related to [decorated variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32589510/can-variables-be-decorated))

```
        @con.notification(int)
        mock_callback = mock.MagicMock()
```

Let me emphasize the order: I want to use a real, unmodified decorator with a mock function.

Comment: Use the non-`@` form, `wrapped_callback = con.notification(int)(mock_callback)`.

Comment: the comment above is the answer.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I didn't know there was a classical notation.I don't agree with the duplicate mark btw. @jonrsharpe I'll accept your answer if you want to post. Otherwise I'll post it myself later to wrap this up.

Comment: How exactly is that _not_ related to decorated variables? You're trying to decorate a variable, and have said that the unsugared version is what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. The goal is not to have a decorated variable, the goal was to put a decorator for a mocked function. The decorated variable is just a pseudo-code illustration.